# Как обработать получение словаря через Python Request

Tags: python, requests, словари

При выполнении request запроса я должен получать словарь в словаре. Как мне теперь обратится к одному из ключей? Если в кратце, то вот такой код:

```
response = requests.get(final_url)
skin = response.text
print(skin)
```

Результат принта:

```
{"iteminfo":{"origin":4,"quality":4,"rarity":2,"a":"19937735378","d":"17151644998212436232","paintseed":976,"defindex":4,"paintindex":799,"stickers":[],"floatid":"19763696990","floatvalue":0.03432495519518852,"m":"3305041656695931456","s":"0","imageurl":"http://media.steampowered.com/apps/730/icons/econ/default_generated/weapon_glock_aa_vertigo_blue_light_large.0f4a3ec87faf17bb8557aa3b57a99606ac24c44e.png","min":0,"max":0.08,"weapon_type":"Glock-18","item_name":"High Beam","rarity_name":"Industrial Grade","quality_name":"Unique","origin_name":"Crafted","wear_name":"Factory New","full_item_name":"Glock-18 | High Beam (Factory New)"}}
```

Возможно забыл что-то елементарное, но уже просто мозг плавится)
Пробовал по разному, не получается:

```
print(skin.get('iteminfo'))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

print(response.get('iteminfo'))
AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Очень мало работал со словарями в таком ключе, поэтому предполагаю, что ответ лежит на поверхности. Буду благодарен всем, кто поможет

P.S.

Спасибо, код skin = response.json() помог, но теперь почему-то не получается получить ключ словаря, который находится в словаре. Накидал вот такой код:

```
response = requests.get(final_url)
skin = response.json()
skin_iteminfo = skin.get('iteminfo')
# paintseed = skin_iteminfo.get('paintseed')
print(skin_iteminfo)
```

Всё работает, в переменной skin_iteminfo имеется вложенный словарь, то есть мне остаётся только обратится к любому из его ключей, но когда я убираю комментарий и пытаюсь вывести один из ключей словаря, который находится в переменной paintseed получаю ошибку AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'. Как такое возможно, если я знаю, что skin_iteminfo это словарь. Не понимаю, в чём заключается ошибка. 
Так же пробовал такой код:

```
paintseed = skin['iteminfo']['paintseed']
```

но получаю ошибку KeyError: 'iteminfo', хотя такой ключ существует

Comment: skin = response.json()

Comment: @MaxU спасибо, помогло решение, но появилась новая проблема. Буду благодарен, если поможете

Comment: Значит в `skin_iteminfo` у вас `None`, а значит в словаре или нет ключа `iteminfo` (если `KeyError: 'iteminfo'` значит ключа нет), или по его значению `None`. Выводите skin и смотрите все ли там на месте

Comment: @gil9red да, я проверял. И переменная skin, и переменная skin_iteminfo выводится без ошибок, в консоли вижу что ключи, которые я пытаюсь получить, существуют. Ошибку получаю именно когда убираю комментарий со строки

Comment: что возвращает `print(type(skin_iteminfo))`?

Comment: прошу прощения, код заработал. Ошибка была в цикле. Так получается, что при первой итерации код всегда работает неправильно (я это видел и просто оставлял, думал что когда разберусь с этой ошибкой буду как-то решать это). Оказалось, что именно эта первая итерация не давала остальным элементам правильно работать. Добавил к циклу [1:] что бы он пропускал первую итерацию и всё заработало. Спасибо кто пытался помочь, даже не думал что по такой причине может возникнуть ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первый вопрос:

```
skin = response.json()
```

Второй вопрос:

```
paintseed = skin['iteminfo']['paintseed']
```

или

```
skin_iteminfo = skin.get('iteminfo')
paintseed = skin_iteminfo.get('paintseed')
```